# WPF C# Binding.SetBinding two-ways binding need PATH or XPATH

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to generate my textboxes dynamically. But I am having problems with setting the binding path of my textbox.

```
//This is my method to generate textboxes.
private void GenerateTextBoxes()
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding
    {
        ElementName = ListViewLists.Name
    };

    TextBox[] textBoxes;

    foreach (DataColumn colum in ViewModel.GeneratedDataTable.Columns)
    {
        DataColumn dataColumn = (DataColumn)colum;

        textBoxes = new TextBox[ViewModel.GeneratedList.Count];

        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < ViewModel.GeneratedList.Count; i++, j++)
        {
            textBoxes[i] = new TextBox
            {
                //Text = myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeText"),
                Name = dataColumn.ColumnName
            };

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBoxes[i], TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);

            // Initialize Labels to show drives.
            Grid.SetRow(textBoxes[i], i);
            Grid.SetColumn(textBoxes[i], 1);
            GridTextBoxes.Children.Add(textBoxes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the method I have this piece of code:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBoxes[i], TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

When I try to run it, it gives me the error two-ways binding need PATH or XPATH, but I do not what it means. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A Binding to the Text property of a TextBox is by default TwoWay. And as the error message clearly says, such a Binding needs a Path to a source property, which you have not set. I also doubt that `ElementName = ListViewLists.Name` makes much sense. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Clemens Ohhh okay, then I need to figure out how to do that. ElementName = ListViewList.name is because I want to try and replicate <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxVoornaam" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItem.xx}" />

Comment: When there is an element with `x:Name="MyListView"`, set the Binding's Source to MyListView in code behind. And of course also set the Path to `new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.xx")`.

Comment: Ohhh I see, but now I am wondering if I can make this dynamic? I tried this:
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem." + dataColumn.ColumnName); but it says that I can not change the binding path after that it has been used.

Comment: Create a new Binding.

Comment: This is a terrible approach. Why aren't you using data binding and a DataTemplate? You'd have a much easier time. Just my two cents.